# Remove white space in gridstack js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gridstack

I have created [gridstack js](https://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/)

The image shows what I have and I have outlined the whitespace (in blue) that I want to remove.

See this image:
[image]

How do I remove this white space?

Comment: This issue has allready been resolved here . https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js/issues/453

Comment: Improving the grammar

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `verticalMargin`.

[Docs](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/tree/develop/doc#grid-options)